# How do I create heatmap matrix in R?

Tags: r

[CSV file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EEcI.png)
Does anyone know the R code to convert this CSV into a heatmap matrix? I want the most used formations to be a deep red colour, and the ones that were only used once to be almost white.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried:

```
heat <- read.csv("formations.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
m <- as.matrix(heat[, -1])
rownames(m) <- heat$Formation
heatmap(m)
```

Comment: Did you try `heatmap(as.matrix(data))` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what has worked, what hasn't? Have you tried searching? Give us more to work with :) [Here are some hints](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make your question better and increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my question after your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(d)
plt <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = Formation, y = variable, fill = value))
plt <- plt + geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient2(low ='white', high = 'red')
plt + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

## data

```
d <- structure(list(Formation = structure(c(7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 
                                           8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 
                                           8L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 3L), 
                                         .Label = c("3-4-1-2", "3-4-2-1", "3-5-1-1", "3-5-2", 
                                                    "4-1-2-1-2", "4-1-4-1", "4-2-3-1", "4-3-3", "4-4-2",
                                                    "5-3-2"), class = "factor"), 
                   variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
                                          4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
                                          5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), 
                                        .Label = c("13/14", "114/15", "115/16", "116/17", "117/18", 
                                                   "118/19"), class = "factor"),
                   value = c(33, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 17, 1, 
                             1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 10, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 6, 
                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), 
              row.names = c(NA, -60L), 
              .Names = c("Formation", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That's brilliant. What line of code would I add if I was loading the csv from the desktop? d <- melt(d) has confused me a bit.

Comment: `d <- read.csv("formations.csv", check.names = FALSE)` It's important to add `check.names = FALSE` because by default, R doesn't like special characters in headers

Comment: here's a good overview of what `melt` from `reshape2` does: https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/

Comment: In short, you want every data parameter you pass to ggplot2 (x, y, fill etc) be a dataframe column; it's not possible unless you convert normal dataframes to 'tall' dataframes using `melt` (or by other means)

Comment: Ok, I tried:<- read.csv("formations.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", check.names = FALSE)
> plt <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = Formation, y = variable, fill = value))
> plt <- plt + geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient2(low ='white', high = 'red')
> plt + theme_minimal()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found

Comment: I think you forgot to melt it (after reading the file, but before plotting)

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Thank you for your help.